# How to save a deep learning model's weight with pickle format?

Tags: deep-learning, pickle, transfer-learning, weighted, pre-trained-model

I am trying to train a model using the transfer learning method.
What command is used to save the weights of the first model with the suffix .pickle?
here is my model but it doesn't work good and I want to try other ways.

def ModelEnhancer():

```
vgg16 = VGG16(weights = "imagenet", include_top = False, input_shape = (256,256,3))
last_layer = vgg16.get_layer('block5_conv3').output
conv4 = vgg16.get_layer('block4_conv3').output
conv3 = vgg16.get_layer('block3_conv3').output
conv2 = vgg16.get_layer('block2_conv2').output
conv1 = vgg16.get_layer('block1_conv2').output

vgg16.trainable = False

# 16 x 16 x 512
uconv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(last_layer)
uconv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(uconv5)
uconv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(uconv5)

# 32 x 32 x 512
deconv4 = Conv2DTranspose(512, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(uconv5)
uconv4 = concatenate([deconv4, conv4])
uconv4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(uconv4)
uconv4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(uconv4)
uconv4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(uconv4)

# 64 x 64 x 256
deconv3 = Conv2DTranspose(256, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(uconv4)
uconv3 = concatenate([deconv3, conv3])
uconv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(uconv3)
uconv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(uconv3)
uconv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(uconv3)

# 128 x 128 x 128
deconv2 = Conv2DTranspose(128, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(uconv3)
uconv2 = concatenate([deconv2, conv2])
uconv2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(uconv2)
uconv2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(uconv2)

# 256 x 256 x 64
deconv1 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(uconv2)
uconv1 = concatenate([deconv1, conv1])
uconv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(uconv1)
uconv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(uconv1)

# 256 x 256 x 1
output_layer = Conv2D(1, (1,1), padding="same", activation="sigmoid")(uconv1)

model = Model(vgg16.input,output_layer)

return model
```